# Include JTextArea or JTextPane in JSP?

Tags: jsp, jtextfield, jtextarea, jtextpane

I want to embed a text are to show the log information of my web application in my jsp file. I am totally new to JSP. I even don't know, which one is more suitable JTextArea, or JTexTPane. Users will not write anything to that area, they will just observe the log from that area. Which one i should select for my purpose and how can i include one of it inside my JSP page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use javax.swing components with JSP unless you are planning to add an java applet to your jsp file.